# How do I make a vbs file delete other files

Tags: vbscript

I have a junk folder that I download stuff to, and every once in a while, I want to clean up the folder by deleting certain files of a certain extension. How would I be able to do that?

Comment: Why vbs? PowerShell is easer: `Get-ChildItem 'C:\junkfolder' '*.txt' | Remove-Item`

Comment: Can I trigger that via a file? Like a .ps1, .vbs, or a .bat?

Comment: With something this brief, easiest thing to do is create a Shortcut with the following as the target: `Powershell -Command "Get-ChildItem 'C:\JunkFolder' '*.txt' | Remove-Item"`

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
target_folder = "INSERT HERE FULL PATH OF FOLDER FROM WHICH YOU WANT TO DELETE ALL .TXT FILES"
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
fs.DeleteFile( target_folder & "\*.txt" )
```

If **"C:\JunkFolder"** is the right path,

then it would be :

```
target_folder = "C:\JunkFolder"
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
fs.DeleteFile( target_folder & "\*.txt" )
```

Paste the above code in a file with the extension .vbs.

If you click the vbs file, every .txt file will be deleted in "C:\JunkFolder"

*"This could be made with a .hta file so you could choose the folder you want to target."*

For those people who want to use this script for deleting all the .txt

in for example a folder in Program Files, but you have User Account Control (UAC) enabled,

use the below script to have a UAC prompt, because without it the script wouldn't do anything.

```
If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
Set sa = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
sa.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", Chr(34) & _
WScript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34) & " uac", "", "runas", 1
Else
target_folder = "PATH BETWEEN THESE QUOTES" Rem <-- Insert the path of the folder you want to target
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
fs.DeleteFile( target_folder & "\*.txt" ) Rem <-- Change the extension txt to another, like pdf, exe, png...
End If
```

Comment: How would I make a HTA file that allows the folder selection?

Answer (score 0):

Voila

I've wrote a simple hta to browse for the folder,

in which you want to remove all the files with a specific extension.

You can enter an extension in the textfield of the hta,

and then click the Browse button to navigate to the desired folder.

Paste the complete code in a text file,

and then change the extension of the text file to .hta

If you cannot see the file extension,

you have to uncheck the checkbox for **Hide extensions for known file types** in folder options.

```
<html>
<head>

<script Language="JScript">
window.resizeTo(0,0);
window.moveTo(-1500,-1500);
</script>

<hta:application
Id="oHTA"
applicationName="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Remove all files with specific extension from a folder&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
border="thin"
borderStyle="no"
caption="no"
contextMenu="yes"
icon="" /** <-- Insert the path of your icon between the quotes */
innerBorder="no"
minimizeButton="no"
maximizeButton="no"
navigable="no"
scroll="no"
scrollFlat="no"
selection="no"
singleInstance="yes"
showInTaskbar="yes"
sysMenu="no"
windowState="normal" />

<script language="JScript">
function position(iWidth,iHeight){
var iLeft = (window.screen.width-iWidth)/2;
var iTop = (window.screen.height-iHeight)/3;
window.moveTo(iLeft,iTop);
window.resizeTo(iWidth,iHeight);
document.title = oHTA.applicationName;}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.minimizeButton
    {Filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient
    (GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#F9F99F',endColorStr='#7F7920');}

.closeButton
     {Filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient
     (GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#F9F99F',endColorStr='#FF3920');}

.folder_choice
    {Filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient
    (GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#F9F99F',endColorStr='#FF0000');}

.extensionInput
    {Filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient
    (GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#F9F99F',endColorStr='#FF0000');}
</style>

<script language="VBScript">
Sub exitOnKeyDown()
    If Window.Event.KeyCode = 13 Then
        window.close()
    End If
End Sub

Sub choose_folder()
On Error Resume Next
    userExtensionChoice = userExtensionInput.value
    If userExtensionChoice = "" Then
        MsgBox "You forgot to enter an extension in the textfield", 4096 + 48,"NO EXTENSION"
            Location.Reload
        Exit Sub
    End If

Set sa = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set bf = sa.BrowseForFolder( 0, "Select the target folder...", 1, "" ) REM Between last quotes you can enter a path which will default open when you start to browse
    If bf Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
            If MsgBox("You selected the folder : " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & bf.Self.path & _
                vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "You chose the file extension '" & userExtensionChoice & "'" & _
                vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Click OK if you want to proceed," & _
                vbCrLf & "or Cancel to abort. ", 4096 + 1 + 64," Check") = 1 Then
                    fs.DeleteFile  bf.Self.path & "\*." & userExtensionChoice
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
    End If
End Sub
</script>

<object Id="MMSize" 
    classid="clsid:adb880a6-d8ff-11cf-9377-00aa003b7a11">
    <param name="command" value="minimize">
</object>

</head>
<body onload="setTimeout('position(200,200)',0)"
        style="border:4px solid #AA000A;">

<textarea
disabled
Style="position:absolute;
border:0px solid transparent;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#CECECE',endColorStr='#FA9100');
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:200px;
height:200px;
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:hidden;">
</textarea>

<input type="text"
    class="extensionInput"
    name="userExtensionInput"
    wrap="off"  
    Style="position:absolute;
    border:3px solid #AA000A;
    top:150px;
    left:67px;
    width:74px;
    height:26px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;"
    title="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Enter the extension of the files you want to delete&nbsp;&nbsp;"/>

<input type="button"
    class="folder_choice"
    onmouseover="this.style.color='#004E98'"
    onmouseout="this.style.color='#000000'"
    Style="position:absolute;
    border:0px solid transparent;
    top:110px;
    left:67px;
    width:74px;
    height:26px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;"
    value="Browse"
    onClick="choose_folder()"
    title="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Browse for folder&nbsp;&nbsp;"/>

<input type="button"
    class="closeButton"
    onmouseover="this.style.color='#FF0000'"
    onmouseout="this.style.color='#000000'"
    style="position:absolute;
    border:0px solid transparent;
    top:21px;
    left:141px;
    width:46px;
    height:26px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;"
    value="EXIT"
    onKeyDown="exitOnKeyDown()"
    onClick="window.close()"
    title="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Close&nbsp;&nbsp;"/>

<input type="button"
    class="minimizeButton"
    onmouseover="this.style.color='#7F7F00'"
    onmouseout="this.style.color='#000000'"
    style="position:absolute;
    border:0px solid transparent;
    top:21px;
    left:21px;
    width:46px;
    height:26px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-Size:14px;"
    value="MIN" 
    onClick="MMSize.Click()" 
    title="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Minimize window&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"/>

<font color="#000000"
    style="position:absolute;
    top:70;
    left:68;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#2E3150;"
    title="&#13;&thinsp;&thinsp;&thinsp;&thinsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dr RedAnt&nbsp;&nbsp;&#13;&thinsp;&thinsp;&thinsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SweetSoft&#13;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Utopia-Gateway&nbsp;&thinsp;&#13;&nbsp;">
    <font Size="2px">Dr RedAnt</font></font>

</body>
</html>
```

This is how the HTA looks

[image: Remove all files with specific extension from a folder]

If you want the file the easy way, then here is a [download link](http://tewoshien.com/downloads/specific_extension_remover.zip)